# How to send push Notification in Mobile App using Microsoft Azure?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have created app in MS Azure and generate API key from firebase console. I want to send broadcast Notification to only GCM mobile users. Is there any reference for that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For sending notifications via Azure Notification Hubs within a backend server, you may leverage the SDK [Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs/) and send notification as follows:

```
var hub = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString("<your hub's DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature>","<hub name>");
var outcome = await hub.SendGcmNativeNotificationAsync("<jsonPayload>");
```

Details you could follow [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/notification-hubs?view=azure-dotnet).

For sending push notifications from the client application, you may use the [Azure Notification Hub REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn223264.aspx).

Here are some tutorials, you could refer to them:

[Azure Notification Hubs Notify Users for Android with .NET backend](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-aspnet-backend-gcm-android-push-to-user-google-notification)

[Send push notifications directly from the Android app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-android-push-notification-google-gcm-get-started#optional-send-push-notifications-directly-from-the-app)